# Can someone please elaborate the solution of magic pairs on CODECHEF platform?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, hashmap

A has some distinct integer numbers a1,a2...an. Count number of pairs (i,j) such that:
1≤ i ≤ n 1≤ j ≤ n ai < aj. the output For each test case, output a single line containing number of pairs for corresponding test case.

My answer :

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int t=sc.nextInt();
        while(t-->0){
            int n=sc.nextInt();
            int a[]=new int[n];
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
                a[i]=sc.nextInt();
            }
            int count=0;
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
                for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
                    if(a[i]<a[j]){
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println(count);
}
```

but it says the time limit exceeds using this solution

but seeing other's solution everyone has used it solving

`System.out.println("n*(n-1)/2");`

can someone please elaborate the significance of `(n*(n-1)/2);`

Comment: That formula is [`n choose 2`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient).

Answer (score 1):

There are several (many) ways to look at this:

If all numbers are distinct, any element `a_i` can form a pair with any other element `a_j`.  So you need to calculate `(n choose 2)` which has the formula `n!/(n-2)!/2!` or `n*(n-1)/2`.

Or you could say that the largest element `a_j` can form `n-1` pairs, the second largest can form `n-2` new pairs, the third largest `n-3` which leads to `(n-1) + (n-2) + (n-3)+...+1` pairs in total.  The closed from sum of this series is `n*(n-1)/2`.